# why does my code execute in the order it does

Tags: javascript, promise, order-of-execution

I am attempting to use promises to ensure certain properties are set before attempting to use those variables later on.

I have managed to piece my way to some code that seems to do what I want but is not in the order I expect given what I have learned about promises.

Creating the promise function wrapper (I think)

```
function skillPromise(char, opts) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        skills_api.getCharactersCharacterIdSkills(char.eve_id, opts, (e, r, b) => {
            if (!e) res(r.total_sp);
            else rej(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Using the promise

```
characters.forEach((c) => {
    skillPromise(c, opts).then((spt) => {
        c.totalSP = spt;
        console.log(spt);
        console.log(c.totalSP);
    }).catch(() => {});
});
console.log(characters);
```

Output

first run

```
[ { eve_id: 123456,
    name: 'name',
    access_token: '',
    refresh_token: '' } ]
4652555
4652555
```

Second run

```
[ { eve_id: 123456,
    name: 'name',
    access_token: '',
    refresh_token: '',
    totalSP: 4652555
  },
  { eve_id: 654321,
    name: 'eman',
    access_token: '',
    refresh_token: '' } ]
9075602
9075602
```

All subsequent runs will follow that pattern.

Forcing a refresh has the same effect as adding a sign-in but also re-prints the values before.

```
[ { eve_id: 123456,
    name: 'name',
    access_token:'',
    refresh_token:'',
    totalSP: 4652555 },
  { eve_id: 654321,
    name: 'eman',
    access_token:'',
    refresh_token:'',
    totalSP: 9075602 } ]
9075602
9075602
```

I guess I just don't understand what I have constructed here.
Mainly its the timing the confuses me.
Why does it do what I expect but in a different order?

EDIT:
I finished adding promise function wrappers to the API callbacks and used `Promise.all()` to resolve them then only rendered the page in the then for it. Basically, it does what I want now.

Two things that I learned when using promise all:

1. if you have function wrappers you can actually pass arguments to them even inside the `promise.all()` call
2. you still get the returns back but they are in an array that is passed to the `.then()`

Promise all

```
Promise.all([skillPromise(c, opts), walletPromise(c, opts), locationPromise(c, opts)]).then((returns) => {
    c.totalSP = returns[0];
    c.walletBalance = returns[1];
    c.solarSystem = returns[2];
    res.render('characters', { characters: characters });
}).catch(() => {});
```

Promise function wrappers:

```
function skillPromise(char, opts) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        skills_api.getCharactersCharacterIdSkills(char.eve_id, opts, (e, r, b) => {
            if (!e) res(r.total_sp);
            else rej(e);
        });
    });
}

function walletPromise(char, opts) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        wallet_api.getCharactersCharacterIdWallet(char.eve_id, opts, (e, r, b) => {
            if (!e) res(r);
            else rej(e);
        });
    });
}

function locationPromise(char, opts) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        location_api.getCharactersCharacterIdLocation(char.eve_id, opts, (e, r, b) => {
            if (!e) {
                // Translate solar_system_id & station_id into System name and Station Name
                universe_api.getUniverseSystemsSystemId(r.solar_system_id, opts, (e, r, b) => {
                    if (!e) res(r.name);
                    else rej(e);
                });
            } else rej(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Promises resolves asynchronously as soon as they are ready. Therefore the order of execution isn't the same as the order of resolution.

Comment: Hi, check out [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) this should help with foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what's happening.
First you execute `forEach`, `forEach`'s callback queues a task (to be executed later by the event loop once the current script finishes) for every call to the callback (which will be called as many times as elements you have in characters array. After queuing these tasks the execution of the script goes on to `console.log(characters);` and that's what you see printed first. Now the script execution is done and the event loop goes to process the task queue, it processes the first tasks added by the `forEach` (this is, one execution of function `skillPromise` which adds a promise to the microtask queue. And it does this for every task the `forEach` loop added. If while processing these tasks some promises get resolved javascript will handle them (not one but all promises which are resolved) after processing the current task queued by the `forEach`. If no promise gets resolved before processing all tasks queued by `forEach` javascript will process all of them afterwards when they are resolved.

So the order is, first we execute `console.log(characters);`, then we handle tasks and promises.

You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&list=PLJiVfwUJVdirAgSFZSqCpq5FFWTIu3gk5) video, I find it a good explanation on how javascript's event loop works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.reduce()` function to wrapper each promise in `then()` of previous promise.

```
characters.reduce((prevPromise, c) => {
    var promise = skillPromise(c, opts).then((spt) => {
            c.totalSP = spt;
            console.log(spt);
            console.log(c.totalSP);
        }).catch(() => {});

    if(prevPromise == null){
        return promise;
    }else{
        prevPromise.then(promise)
    }
}, null);
```